# Would this case be a good fit for $q?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble figuring out if I should be using `$q` for the following psuedo-coded scenario:

```
function create() {

    if (condition1) {
        // ajax call that needs to update
        // the object to be passed into Service.create()
    }

    if (condition2) {
        // ajax call that doesn't make updates to object
    }

    Service.create(object).success(function() {
        // the object was passed here
    });

}
```

Note: `condition1` and `condition2` are mutually exclusive.

Previously, I did something like this:

```
function create() {

    if (condition1) {
        // on ajax success
        callServiceCreate(object);
        return;
    }

    if (condition2) {
        // ajax call that doesn't make updates to object
    }

    callServiceCreate(object);

}

function callServiceCreate(object) {

    Service.create(object).success(function() {
        // the object was passed here
    });

}
```

And that works, but I'm wondering if this case would be a good fit for $q.

If I wrap `condition1` with a $q constructor:

```
if (condition1) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        // ajax success
        resolve(data);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same functionality but call `callServiceCreate()` / `Service.create()` only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could obviously use `$q.when` here that will pass promise `when` function

**Code**

```
function create() {
    var condition1Promise;
    if (condition1) {
        condition1Promise = callServiceCreate(object);
    }

    if (condition2) {
        // ajax call that doesn't make updates to object
    }

    $q.when(condition1Promise).then(function(){
        Service.create(object).success(function() {
            // modify object here
            // the object was passed here
        });
    })
}

function callServiceCreate(object) {
    //returned promise from here to perform chain promise
    return Service.create(object).then(function(data) {
        // the object was passed here
        return data;
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this is going to take me some time to wrap my head around.  You are defining a promise as the result of a function and defining that function with a return.  Okay, so the data is returned to the promise.  Is $q.when always triggered or only when `condition1` is true?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I returned a promise from function because I wanted to perform chain promise mechanism here..And yes your guess is correct `$q.when` gets evaluated only when it gets resolved,